# How to set ggplot2 with two levels of color and three levels of linetype

Tags: r

I have been trying all this afternoon, but still didn't make it work. 
I have a data frame with four variables, something like this,

```
       fpr tpr col lty
        0  0.000 red   a
        0  0.002 red   a
        0  0.004 red   a
        0  0.006 red   a
        0  0.008 red   a
        0  0.010 red   a
```

The first two columns is what I want to use for plot. The last two columns is used to specify the color and linetype. I have three levels of colours, which are 'red', 'blue', 'green', and two levels of linetypes, which are 'a' and 'd' (stands for solid and dashed lines). But when I use the following code

```
            ggplot() + scale_color_identity() + scale_linetype_identity()+
            geom_line( data=dataf, aes( x=fpr, y=tpr, colour=col, linetype=lty ))
```

I was not able to produce the figure I want (Sorry I am not eligible to upload figures at this time....)
Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: `a` is not a recognised linetype

Comment: Describe the results and how they differ from what you expect or desire.

Comment: Provide a link to the pictures and one of us can edit the post and include them.

Comment: To expand on what baptiste said, you can't use an identity scale if you aren't providing valid values. `linetype` has to be one of 'solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Following works (remove scale_linetype_identity()):

```
ggplot() + scale_color_identity()+ geom_line( data=dataf, aes( x=fpr, y=tpr, colour=col, linetype=lty ))
```

[image]